# Make the scene in Storyboard longer or scrolling in it

Tags: iphone, xcode, interface, uiscrollview, storyboard

I'm working in the storyboard, and one of my scrollviews is way longer than the iPhone screen (to display some long text). In the simulator it's no problem to scroll but is there some way to scroll down the scrollview in the storyboard??

I have a slight memory of seeing a tutorial where the screen in the storyboard was "stretched"  longer so it shows the whole scrollview. But that may have been in a dream. Someone who knows how to do something like this?

Edit:

The answer below says that can you scroll through the scrollview with a two finger drag, but I can't. Could it be because the scrollview is placed directly in the ViewController without a UIView behind it? Should I have a UIView behind anyways? It works fine this way except I can't scroll through in the Storyboard..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can scroll within a scroll view in the storyboard with a two-finger drag. I'm not aware of a method to make the visible part of the scroll view bigger than the device screen within a storyboard.

Don't know what you'd do with a "normal" mouse either!

Comment: Could it be because my scrollview is placed directly in the ViewController without a UIView behind it? Do I need that?

Comment: If you've just changed the class of the main view to UIScrollView, scrolling will not work. You actually need to drag in a UIScrollView from the toolbar in Xcode. I'm not sure if this is what you mean by having it "placed directly in the ViewController" though, as normally you can't drag in a ViewController without bringing the view along.

Comment: Putting the UIScrollView directly onto the ViewController works fine in the simulator, but later on it caused a LOT of truouble leading to this question and other mess. Adding a view between them solved it all.

Comment: With a normal mouse you select the scroll view and use the scroll wheel to navigate within it.

Answer (score 0):

In the storyboard there is a default view and I don't know how to expand.  But you can scroll within it by clicking at the top or black part at bottom which causes the entire window to highlight.  Than using a scrolling mouse wheel, you can scroll up or down.